# What is the "Minimum" of beliefs to be considered Orthodox?

Tags: orthodox, ikarim

In trying to understand Orthodox Judaism better, I would like to know what constitutes the "minimum" or most basic collection of beliefs. As I understand, agreeing with the 13 Principles of Maimonides is a great start, but I am a little confused on the exact nature of belief about the Talmud. As well, how much of a margin is there for personal opinion? Thus, I would like to know:

**What is the most basic collection of beliefs absolutely required for one to be considered Orthodox (esp. MO, and ignoring other, non-belief related requirements, such as one's actual practicing of mitzvot)?**

Comment: God, Who gave us these binding laws, takes an active role in the world.

Comment: It has nothing to do with belief. Actions speak louder than words. In accordance with Law, I believe that while a person's laxness within a specific area of law renders them not trustworthy in just that area, not observing the sabbath makes them untrustworthy in any matter of Jewish law. So Sabbath practical observance is the 'bottom line' of being considered an observant jew, generally.

Comment: @DoubleAA, the way I see the binding of mitzvot is that it is the (active) conclusion resulting from a belief, that belief having to do more directly with Orthodoxy's view of the Talmud, of which I am not fully certain about.

Comment: @BabySeal. Thank you. I was actually hoping you might say something to that effect. However, is it possible to live as an Orthodox Jew (performing mitzvot, studying Torah, Talmud, etc.) and yet believing that they are human creations and an aspect of socio-religious development)? As well, in DoubleAA's defense, belief's have consequences and one who doesn't act on his beliefs has a questionable commitment to those beliefs.

Comment: @MonicaCellio. Very nice and clean :). Thank you!

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that given two axes (beliefs and actions) people can fall into four possibilities (not counting the fact that people are not necessarily consistent day-to-day).  I know members of an Orthodox shul that 1) believe and do (thus consider themselves Orthodox), 2) believe but don't do (and thus don't self-identify as Orthodox), and 3) don't believe but do. At the beginning of the twentieth century, it was common in America for immigrants to belong to an Orthodox shul, but not personally keep all of the mitzvot (case 2). This is less common today, but still exists.

Comment: By law, I believe so. Obviously I am just a baby seal and not a rabbi though, so I'd double check. Given societal tendencies and human nature though, I think that people would not be accepting if you were open about those beliefs. I also agree with you. I would wonder about your ability to maintain the laws, even of just the Sabbath, as they oftentimes are very inconveniencing, and it would take real grit to consider them binding and inviolable if the perception of them was that they were just human constructs. I'm thinking that this question will be really tough to answer objectively.

Comment: Does the person who believes that the laws are human-made *also* believe that a God is Orchestrating humanity to a degree, by granting them knowledge and thought? Because if so that is arguably exactly what the Orthodox perception of the Oral Law is.

Comment: Rambam Yesodei Hatorah

Comment: @sam despite its name, there are several key ideas missing from Yesodei HaTorah, that (according to the Rambam) one would still be a heretic without believing them. The actual list is in Hilchos Teshuvah

Comment: @babyseal observance is simply the best way we can estimate how much to trust someone because we have no way of telling what they believe

Comment: @Daniel perhaps, or perhaps it is mechanically what converts a person from "trustworthy" to "not trustworthy", rather than a estimating decisor.

Comment: Orthodox is a social definition if you want to study a group, you need a sociological study. If you speech ab about the princple of Maimonides, it is a problem of definition, see Sefer Haykarim about what is  a principle ...
A belief and a social position are specific of separated domain. Socially speaking, there is no place for beliefs, but for clothes, habits etc. Orthodox judaism is a reaction against haskala. But the Halacha is the same as for ever.

Comment: There was an interesting article on this in the Techumim serires (in hebrew). It looked at various minimum requirements such as what various committees in history used as markers for religiosity. For example, in Israel, there are 'religious' (orthodox) moshavim, some of which had requirements for entry e.g., kashrut, shabbat observance, family purity. The article outlined a bunch of them. If I ever find it again...

Answer (score 2):

"Orthodox" as a label originated as a slur for the traditionally observant by the new Reform movements of the 19th century (Samson Raphael Hirsch, Religion Allied to Progress, in JMW. p. 198). Presumably, what you're asking is what beliefs are assumed to be incompatible with a Torah lifestyle even amongst the more open-minded of Torah personalities that represent the halachik MO movement.  Probably the only clear cut guideline beyond Maimonides' 13 principles is a general tone of respect to the Talmudic sages and their views ("An Apikoros. Rav and R' Chanina both taught that this means one who disrespects a Talmid Chacham [Torah scholar].—Tractate Sanhedrin, 99b)

Answer (score 2):

As far as the Talmud goes? The law within it is binding, and its legal interpretations of Biblical verses are of Biblical force.

Comment: But importantly, although rabbis are authorized to use _derashot_ to invent new laws, these laws were not transmitted at Sinai, and can be overturned by later courts according to Rambam. Cf. Shoresh Sheni in Sefer HaMitzvot of Rambam and Hilchot Mamrim. This can be an miportant point for someone who grapples with "belief" in the Talmud.

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum of beliefs. In theory to say you believe "this part" of the Torah but not "another part" of the Torah would be to reject the premise of the Torah being given to us by Gd which falls into being outside the scope of Judaism.

Comment: Belief in the Torah is one of the 13 core beliefs. "This part or that part" is not the issue. There are 12 more. The Akeidah states 3 core general beliefs. 1. That HaShem exists and 2. He gave us a way to live, expressed in the Torah, written and oral and 3. He cares whether we follow the Torah or not (therefore: reward or punishment.) Maimonides expands those 3 into 13 core specific beliefs.

Comment: It is relevant b/c even denying one letter of the Torah would be outside the scope of valid Judaism.